# python using popen without shell, or assert to increase safety

Tags: python, regex, shell, assert, popen

Using subprocess.popen to call an external program within my script. I have been unable to get it to work without shell=True, and have added an assert statement to make things less dangerous (I think).

Relevant code lines:

```
import subprocess
import re
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="options")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--prefix", help="prefix for output files")
args = parser.parse_args()

assert re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$", args.prefix), "non-alphanumeric characters found"

command = "my_external_program -t type -f %s -m 1 -M 1 -N 0 -H -p 16" % args.prefix
external_stacks_call = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=open(args.prefix + ".log.txt", "a"), stderr=open(args.prefix + ".log.txt", "a"))
external_stacks_call.wait()
```

questions are as follows:

1. is the assert statment safe enough to avoid mischief/problems by others, or other unanticipated problems?

   1. for example someone entering a prefix of "stuff && rm -rf /"
2. what is the best way to not call this same string without the shell=True option?

I have looked at several pages here and elsewhere about the dangers of the shell=True option, and the dangers of shell=True, but I have not found a good source of how to avoid using it for an external program

Comment: why are you using shell=True?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham without it the command won't execute ... this is the first time I've tried to call an external program from within python

Comment: call .split on command and remove shell=True, then use .communicate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shell=True` will escape the spaces, however you can also provide a list of args for the command line

```
command = ["my_external_program", "-t", "type", "-f", str(args.prefix), 
           "-m", "1", "-M", "1", "-N", "0", "-H", "-p", "16"]
```

This will allow the module to interface with the shell correctly, more safely

Without `shell=True` special characters will be escaped, so the equivalent of your original command would be

```
$ my_external_program\ -t\ type\ -f
```

etc.

This is an advantage because the shell can then escape all kinds of special characters in the same way

Comment: Is it correct to say then that " ".join(command) is basically called on subprocess.popen(command)? and that this will avoid the problems with having user input going into the external command string?

Comment: @ded, no: `subprocess.Popen(" ".join(command), shell=True)` is not a general equivalent to `subprocess.Popen(command, shell=False)`. For instance, the former would execute the subcommand in a prefix of `$(rm -rf /)`, whereas the latter would (correctly and safely) pass the string through literally. Likewise, the former opens you up to bugs such as shellshock. Using `shell=False` is the Right Thing unless you have a specific and compelling reason to do otherwise, and have carefully considered the security implications.